# MySQL Include() does not work in EF .NET Core 2

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, .net-core, eager-loading, .net-core-2.0

I have a MySQL database where the table Game has a FK to the table GameStats (Game.GameStatsId -> GameStats.GameStatsId), but can't get it to load when fetching Games with:

```
var games = _context.Game.Include(g => g.GameStats).ToList();
```

When it logs the SQL query, no JOIN is done, but rather just a normal SELECT from Game.

However, I *can* do a explicit Load() of the related GameStats data after this:

```
_context.Entry(games[0]).Reference(g => g.GameStats).Load();
```

..so I guess something works. But why doesn't the `Include()` work? What have I missed?

The EF classes are generated from an existing DB with scaffold, and I'm on a Mac. Using MySql.Data.EntityframeworkCore 6.10.6 and have also tried [Pomelo](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) but with the same result.

Comment: have you by any chance resolved this issue

Comment: I switched to PostgreSQL instead :-)